# Sort strings in array by length using jq

Tags: docker, tags, jq, gcloud

I am grabbing a list of all docker tags from GCP via the gcloud cli

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/my_image --format=json | jq -S .[].tags
```

the output:

```
[
  "build.160",
  "ed37ba0ea1f31d62ff48ef817addd30c8be9952c"
]
[
  "5cd7190a96f633cfb8b5fa0f876f147dbe700dad",
  "build.161"
]
[
  "9a9f030fcf7544565b9ebf8ba37330b649e156ba",
  "build.159"
]
```

Is there a way to sort the values to keep consistency? That way it can look like this:

```
[
  "ed37ba0ea1f31d62ff48ef817addd30c8be9952c",
  "build.160"
]
[
  "5cd7190a96f633cfb8b5fa0f876f147dbe700dad",
  "build.161"
]
[
  "9a9f030fcf7544565b9ebf8ba37330b649e156ba",
  "build.159"
]
```

Comment: Can you paste the original JSON without doing -S in jq?

Comment: Hey @Inian is the same output with or without the -S . Also there might be an occurrence where there might be 3-4 tags as well. I'm just trying to make sure they follow some order.

I guess from the docker/GCP side it depends which docker tags got pushed fisrt/last

Comment: @jrow - A better solution would probably be possible if you showed a representative snippet of the output of the gcloud command, before applying the jq filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `sort_by` on the length of the strings in the array and reverse the order to keep the longest string first. Remove the `reverse` function to keep the shortest string first

```
sort_by(length) | reverse
```

Comment: Well that was easy enough! I had no idea you can sort by the length of the value for each. Thank you @Inian